# Web resources in subfolders not loading on domain but work fine with the IP address

Tags: php, html

I have hosted a website using PHP and MySQL on ubuntu. It worked well but somehow suddenly, web resources are not loading when the URL includes the domain but do load when the URL contains the IP address.

eg. `mywebsite.com` is working fine but `mywebsite.com/anything` is not `XXX.XX.XX/anything` is working just fine.

Please help me in finding the source of the problem. I checked the subfolders, all files are present there.

Apache.conf file:
[image]

Conf file in sites available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.org
        ServerAlias www.mywebsite.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Error logs:
Server Log: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend
Browser o: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check your browser’s developer tools to see what error you are receiving, and also check the server’s logs

Comment: Server Log (Apache): HTTP: failed to make connection to backend
Browser Log: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You really need to provide some more detail on the web server and file structure. Some var_dumps and improving on the question you might well answer this yourself. If httpd maybe try changing conf to facilitate browsing, eg. `Options All Indexes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the domain name. the URL was being redirected to the wrong IP